# Bash or Powershell to move files of a certain size to directories of a certain naming convention

Tags: bash, powershell

We have a list of clients under a top level "Clients" folder on a filer. Under the Clients folder are the actual client folders, some with the naming convention "client_test" others "111_1111". I need to scan all the subfolders for clients that will all have *_[0-9]like the 111_1111 client and replace the footer.jpg if it is 4903 bytes or less with a new footer.jpg. Basically if the client has modified the footer from the original we want to leave it but if not would like to overwrite the footer with a new rebranded footer. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: where will you get the replacement footer.jbg file? will it be the same for all, or will it be per-customer?

Comment: I have a new rebranded footer.jpg I can place wherever I need to. It will be the same for all clients that have a folder structure like the above 111_1111 if the file is the 4903 byte footer.jpg. If its larger , or smaller for that matter. I am assuming the customer has customized the footer to match the brand and do not want to overwrite. Thanks!

Comment: kool! i will see if i can wrangle something tonite ... or possibly tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the paths as appropriate, I think this bit of PowerShell would do the trick. Test first to see if this rounds up the files you want to replace:

```
gci c:\Clients\*\footer.jpg |
   ?{($_.directory.name -match ''^\d+-\d+$') -and ($_.length -eq 4904)}
```

If that works, use the following:

```
gci c:\Clients\*\footer.jpg |
   ?{($_.directory.name -match '^\d+-\d+$') -and ($_.length -eq 4904)} |
       %{copy-item 'c:\NewArtwork\footer.jpg' "$($_.directory)\footer.jpg" -force}
```

- gci = Get-ChildItem
- ?   = Where-Object
- %   = ForEach-Object

Keith